# Add custom property to ThemeData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I need to change `color` of a widget based on theme. I have separate `ThemeData` for light and dark theme. Now is it possible to add a custom property to `ThemeData` so that I can change the color of the widget based on theme and using that custom property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding custom property, we can extend `ThemeData` by `extension` function. For example, if we need a custom property for color, we can add `extension` function on `ColorScheme`. `Color` dependencies are now moved to `Themedata`.

```
// checking brightness to support dynamic themeing
extension CustomColorSchemeX on ColorScheme {
  Color get smallBoxColor1 =>
      brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey[400];
}
```

And then access that property through `Theme.of(context)...`

```
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .colorScheme
                                    .smallBoxColor1),
                        ),
```

Comment: No, you can't. Let's say if you have 10 different `ThemeData`. How would you differentiate them all? Just by using  `Brightness`? What you're doing is just a workaround for specific cases where people only have 2 different Themes that differs by "brightnesses".

Answer (score 13):

Flutter has recenty introduced [ThemeExtensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-szcYzFVao) (thanks [@guilherme-matuella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8558606/guilherme-matuella) for the [PR link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/98033)!)

You can get a pretty good idea on how to use the functionality by following [examples](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/api/lib/material/theme/theme_extension.1.dart#L71) from the main Flutter repo:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: MyApp._title,
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      const MyColors(
        brandColor: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
        danger: Color(0xFFE53935),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      const MyColors(
        brandColor: Color(0xFF90CAF9),
        danger: Color(0xFFEF9A9A),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  themeMode: isLightTheme ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
  home: Home(
    isLightTheme: isLightTheme,
    toggleTheme: toggleTheme,
  ),
);
```

Which you can later retrieve in your widget like so:
`final MyColors myColors = Theme.of(context).extension<MyColors>();`

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

It appears that you now can do exactly what you want, please check the [answer below by Nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72347083/8558606).

---

**OLD ANSWER:**
Sadly, it appears that [you simply can't](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16487) - and the Flutter team doesn't seem to be interested in adding this, given their suggestion.

I think this is a major flaw, because we can't benefit from `Theme.of(context)` to automatically update all of our `Widget` that consume this `ThemeData`.

While some may say that you can use extensions to add new properties, you effectively won't know how to differ between multiple `ThemeData` (unless you can use some properties like `Brightness`, but I think this is just too hacky and not reliable to do so).

The alternative is to create another `InheritedWidget` (just like they said in the issue mentioned above) to handle your custom theme properties.

Edit: It seems that a [new PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/98033) has introduced the possibility to extend the `ThemeData`, but it hasn't landed in main or even stable yet.

Comment: With extension function I think I can't get dynamic themeing.

Comment: Actually we can use `extension` and can have dynamic themeing. I've added answer.

Comment: Have you read my response? What you have done is simply differ between multiple `ThemeData` based on a property like `Brightness`. Nonetheless, I've added a more in-depth response to your answer.